# Any way to bypass validations and still update bean values?

Tags: ajax, jsf, jakarta-ee, richfaces

I use Richfaces. I am facing a situation where I have a form and 2 buttons. On click of one of the buttons, say button1, I need the validations. On click of another, button2,  I dont. The issue arises when I click on the button1 and I get all validation error messages. This prevents clicking of button2. I tried ajaxSingle, immediate, which help in bypassing the validations but bean values are not updated. How can I achieve that ?

Code :

```
<h:inputSecret value="#{bean.value} redisplay="true"/>
<a4j:commandButton immediate="true" actionListener="#{bean.actionListener} reRender="ID_OF_PANEL_SURROUNDING_THIS_CODE"/>
```

Bean :w

```
public class bean {
.
.
.
public void actionListener(ActionEvent e) {
value = "New value";
}
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set **immediate** attribute to **true** in your second button.

**Immediate** attribute skips validation of your values but using **immediate** for anything other than the trivial case of a **cancel button** is problematic. If your **button2** is some kind of cancel button there is no problem.

If you need to implement something more complex than a cancel button there are some solutions to these **problems** which you can find in below article.

[How_The_Immediate_Attribute_Works](http://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/How_The_Immediate_Attribute_Works)

Comment: Thanks for the info and the link. However, if I use immediate=true, validations are passed but data changed by the bean code is not reflected. That is the issue.

Comment: I think solution 1 part of the article is your what you are looking for. Use immediate and a valueChangeListener. BTW if you update your question with a little of your code. I can help more.

Comment: I have updated the question. The button mentioned here is button2.

Comment: Ended up creating a custom validator and I am calling it manually in actionlistener.

Answer (score 1):

What is actually possible to do for such case is writing a custom validator and do the relevant checks in it.

conditionalValidation.xhtml:

Please notice the `h:inputHidden` that agregate ids and trigger custom validator to be invoked.

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"  
    template="/WEB-INF/template/default.xhtml">

    <ui:param name="title" value="Conditional Validation"/>
    <ui:param name="bean" value="#{conditionalValidationBean}"/>

    <ui:define name="content">
        <a4j:form id="frmConditionalValidation">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputLabel for="txtValue1" value="Value 1"/>
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:inputText id="txtValue1" value="#{bean.value1}"/>
                    <h:message for="txtValue1"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
                <h:outputLabel for="txtValue2" value="Value 2"/>
                <h:panelGroup>
                    <h:inputText id="txtValue2" value="#{bean.value2}"/>
                    <h:message for="txtValue2"/>
                </h:panelGroup>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:inputHidden id="inpDetailsProvider" required="true"
                validator="#{bean.conditionalValidator}" value="1">
                <f:attribute name="forceValidationBtnId" value="btnForceValidation"/>
                <f:attribute name="value1InputId" value="txtValue1"/>
                <f:attribute name="value2InputId" value="txtValue2"/>
            </h:inputHidden>
            <h:commandButton id="btnForceValidation" value="Force Validation"/>
            <h:commandButton id="btnByPassValidation" value="Bypass Validation"/>
        </a4j:form>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

ConditionalValidationBean.java

```
public class ConditionalValidationBean {

    private String value1;
    private String value2;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void conditionalValidator(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        String forceValidationBtnId = (String) component.getAttributes().get("forceValidationBtnId");
        String value1InputId = (String) component.getAttributes().get("value1InputId");
        String value2InputId = (String) component.getAttributes().get("value2InputId");

        UIViewRoot viewRoot = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot();
        UICommand forceValidationBtn = findComponent(viewRoot, forceValidationBtnId, UICommand.class);

        Map<String, String> params = context.getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        boolean forceValidation = params.containsKey(forceValidationBtn.getClientId(context)); 

        if(forceValidation) {
            UIInput value1Input = findComponent(viewRoot, value1InputId, UIInput.class);
            UIInput value2Input = findComponent(viewRoot, value2InputId, UIInput.class);

            String v1 = (String) value1Input.getValue();
            if(v1 == null || v1.trim() == "") {
                value1Input.setValid(false);
                FacesMessage valueRequiredMsg = new FacesMessage("Value required");
                context.addMessage(value1Input.getClientId(context), valueRequiredMsg);
            }

            // Rest of validation logic.
        }
    }

    public static <T> T findComponent(UIComponent base, String id, Class<T> returnType) {
        if (id.equals(base.getId())) {
            return returnType.cast(base);
        }

        Iterator<UIComponent> children = base.getFacetsAndChildren();

        while (children.hasNext()) {
            T found = findComponent(children.next(), id, returnType);

            if (found != null) {
                return returnType.cast(found);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }    

    public String getValue1() {
        return value1;
    }

    public String getValue2() {
        return value2;
    }

    public void setValue1(String value1) {
        this.value1 = value1;
    }

    public void setValue2(String value2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

}
```